# Zokrates can't find standard library

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm just following a  Zokrates example. I have a problem when compiling main.zok. Zokrates can't find standard library.

[image]
and this is main.zok code. It's just from Zokrates tutorial.

[image]

I read that setting up `$ZOKRATES_HOME` environmental variables to `stdlib` is required. I make a new system variable `ZOKRATES_HOME` to 'C:\Users\ansth\ZoKrates\zokrates_stdlib\stdlib'. and add `%ZOKRATES_HOME%` in Path in system variable.

Why can't it be compiled? Is there something wrong with environmental variables?

Answer (score 0):

If newer versions is unable to find stdlib it throws: `Invalid standard library source path: ~/.zokrates/stdlib`

Have you tried [setting](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates/issues/264) `ZOKRATES_STDLIB` variable?